# JSON Specification for Column/View formatting?

Tags: list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, view-formatting

I am new to column and view formatting but see the power for my users. However, despite the wealth of examples between Microsoft docs and GitHub and the schema itself, I'm looking for descriptions of the many properties and acceptable values.

Example for column Style/width: can take a string input for pixel count like "40px", but also % value? I saw "11px 0" in some examples but can't figure the effect of this syntax.

Are there any detailed technical specs available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, width property in style can take the value in pixels(px) as well as percentage(%).

This question is more related to the CSS. You can read more about its syntax at: [CSS width Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp).

Also, check below official documentations for column and view formatting.

**References**:

1. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).
2. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting).

Comment: CSS! That's the hint I needed. W3's CSS reference has all the definitions and syntax I've been looking for. That's probably an obvious link for veteran SharePoint admins, though I'm surprised MS docs doesn't mention it. Thank you!